# No route matches when specifying 'path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

routes:

```
  resources :news_items, :path => 'news', :as => 'news' do
   collection do
     get 'all' => 'news_items#news'
  end
```

controller:

```
def new
  @news = NewsItem.new
  @news.file_uploads.build

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @news }
  end
end
```

form:

```
<%= form_for(@news, :html => {:class=>'form-stacked', :multipart => true}) do |f| %>
  <% if @news.errors.any? %>
```

When I run rake routes

```
          all_news_index GET    /news/all(.:format)                 {:action=>"news", :controller=>"news_items"}
          news_index GET    /news(.:format)                     {:action=>"index", :controller=>"news_items"}
                     POST   /news(.:format)                     {:action=>"create", :controller=>"news_items"}
            new_news GET    /news/new(.:format)                 {:action=>"new", :controller=>"news_items"}
           edit_news GET    /news/:id/edit(.:format)            {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"news_items"}
                news GET    /news/:id(.:format)                 {:action=>"show", :controller=>"news_items"}
                     PUT    /news/:id(.:format)                 {:action=>"update", :controller=>"news_items"}
                     DELETE /news/:id(.:format)                 {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"news_items"}
```

When I go to '/news/new' I get:

```
No route matches {:path_prefix=>"news", :controller=>"news_items", :format=>nil}
```

when I go to '/news/4/edit' I get:

```
No route matches {:path_prefix=>"news", :action=>"show", :controller=>"news_items", :format=>nil, :id=>#<NewsItem id: 4,...
```

Comment: What is your controller called, and in which file does it reside?

Comment: @meagar NewsItemsController && news_items_controller.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with the `form_for(@news)` line.

This will create a form, for which the URL is inferred by the class of @news.

It seems this is of class `NewsItem`, so it will try to link to `news_items_path`.

You should try stating the url explicitly.

```
form_for(@news, :url => news_path(@news))
```

Comment: This worked better since I'm using the form for both new and edit: :url => (@news.id.nil? ? new_news_path : news_path(@news)). Thanks for the tip!